# Command-line tool to capture and apply differences between two folders

Tags: command-line, rsync

I am looking for a command line tool that allows me to do two things:

1. I give it two folders (paths)

   and it creates a delta file containing all the differences between the two folders.

   This file must allow later, "to apply" these differences on the 1st folder, in order to obtain the second one.

   Example of use =>

   `compute-deltas /path/folder1/ /path/folder2/ -o delta-file`

   and I get a delta-file
2. I give it a folder and a delta-file, and it "applies" all the differences to the folder

   `apply-deltas /path/folder1/ delta-file -o /path/folder2/`

   Before running the command => `/path/folder2/` is an empty or non-existent folder

   After executing the command => `/path/folder2/` is completely restored from folder1 and delta-file

Here is an idea of how it would work, if an existing tool comes to your mind, please let me know, thanks!

It would be like archiving (or making an image) of an rsync run, and then applying it (running it) later.

Comment: If you're talking about text files this is what diff and patch are for, there's various bulk-work/industrial upgrades from there depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In my case, it's folders, not text files. I just did a new search for "diff and patch for folder", and I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9980186/4135158 You have put me on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

> The rdiff utility uses the rsync algorithm to generate delta files with the difference from file A to file B (like the utility diff, but in a different delta format). The delta file can then be applied to file A, turning it into file B (similar to the patch utility). rdiff works well with binary files.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#rdiff

https://superuser.com/a/1523459/775371

> rdiffdir is supposed to be like rdiff, but can operate on directories.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiffdir